# How can I make an a tag link to html text rather than a file?

Tags: html

For a project of mine, could I have an a tag link to html text rather than an url?

ex.

```
<a target = "_blank" href = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head></head><body>Hello World!</body></html>">
    Click Here!
</a>
```

Comment: It's better to read the specification about [anchor element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) before asking

Comment: @PoulBak — You can.

Comment: @AlonEitan – That isn't the specification, and it doesn't describe how to achieve this anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, and no.

The value of the `href` attribute has to be a URL.

However, you can encode the entire document into the URL by using [the `data:` URL scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme).

```html
<a href="data:text/html;base64,PCFET0NUWVBFIGh0bWw+PGh0bWw+PGhlYWQ+PC9oZWFkPjxib2R5PkhlbGxvIFdvcmxkITwvYm9keT48L2h0bWw+">Link</a>
```

Comment: I'm not sure how that would be useful in practice, but it is none the less awesome!

Comment: It is more commonly used to inline images in style sheets to save on HTTP requests.